# Check if there is a knot between piecewise linear line connecting finite number of points

Tags: general-topology, geometry, knot-theory

I have a finite number of ordered points connected by a piecewise linear curve, which connects all the points in order and then the last with the first one. Can I check if there is a “knot” in this piecewise linear curve?

Comment: Without knowing much of knot theory, it looks this issue can be settled through projections onto for example the x-y coordinate plane, looking at each intersection of projections of 2 line segments which one is above which one in the initial 3D configuration.

Comment: @JeanMarie Is it possible to prove that given a basis of three vectors, if you find no intersection on all three projections then there is no knot?

Comment: That is given $b_1, b_2,b_3$ basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and for any vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ letting $\text{proj}_{b_i}(v)$ denote the projection of point $v$ by $b_i$. Can we say that the projection of all vectors connecting the ordered points with respect to all the basis vectors have no intersections then there is no knot?

Comment: A projection onto a one-dimensional vector cannot bring information. One needs projections onto planes with basis $\{b_i,b_j\}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie yeah sorry by that projection I mean the projection on the plane of the OTHER two vectors. Or rather onto the plane with normal vector $b_i$

Comment: If indeed the projection on one of the coordinate planes has no self-intersection, it means that it is un-knotted ; the proof for that is that projection is a "legit deformation" in this case into a curve diffeomorphic to a circle. But the reciprocal must not be true. I must take time (and check by computer) to give a thorough answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie what is the definition of “legit transformation” here?

Comment: I should have said that it is a "homotopic transformation".

Comment: It can be done.  See https://video.ucdavis.edu/media/quasipolynomial-unknot/1_w3i5jvqi ... brief description at https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/38304

Comment: @brainjam I am not sure that’s the same problem

Comment: @brainjam my points are connected by a piecewise linear curve and from what I gather the “unknot” is the ability to deform the curve to remove a knot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I check if there is a “knot” in this piecewise linear [PL] curve?

The answer is yes, but it can be difficult, depending on how tangled the curve is.   I'm assuming that you want an automated method.  Here are some things to try.

##### Find a planar projection with no intersections

For a curve that isn't too tangled, it may be possible to find a projection that has no intersections.  This means the curve is an "[unknot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknot)" (i.e. not a knot, contains no knots).  If you can't find such a projection, your curve may or may not contain a knot.

##### Check whether the total curvature is less than $4\pi$

The [Fáry–Milnor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%E2%80%93Milnor_theorem) states that smooth curves with small total curvature $(\le4\pi)$ must be unknotted.  This [generalizes to PL curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%E2%80%93Milnor_theorem#Generalizations_to_non-smooth_curves).  If your PL curve has total curvature $\gt 4\pi$ it may or may not contain a knot.

##### Use knot theory techniques

Knot theory applies to both smooth curves and PL curves.  One of the big preoccupations of knot theory is unknot recognition (and knot equivalence in general). Knots have associated polynomials, and the Jones Polynomial in particular can be used to distinguish most if not all knots from the unknot.  A gentle introduction can be found in [Conrad, *The Knot Book*](https://archive.org/details/knotbookelementa0000adam/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater). (can be temporarily "borrowed" from archive.org).

##### Use untangling techniques from computational geometry

As mentioned, even simple knots can be unrecognizable if they are sufficiently tangled.  But there is software to address the problem.  The most impressive I've seen is [Yu, Schumacher, Crane, *Repulsive Curves*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ekmcrane/Projects/RepulsiveCurves/index.html).  Methods like this may help pre-process your PL curves so they are easier to use with the first three methods.  In particular, if you have a gnarly unknot, Repulsive Curves should turn this into a nice circle or oval.